# How to print an increase and decrease array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

For example

The list should be print like this:

```
0
0 1 
0 1 2
0 1 2 3
```

```
0 1 2 3
0 1 2
0 1
0
```

Comment: This is easily possible with loops or Array methods. What exactly isn’t working in the attempts you’ve made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a nested `for` loop:

```js
const list = [0, 1, 2, 3]
for (let i = 1; i <= list.length; i++) {
  var str = '';
  for (let j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    str += list[j]+' ';
  }
  console.log(str);
}


for (let i = list.length; i > 0; i--) {
  var str = '';
  for (let j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    str += list[j]+' ';
  }
  console.log(str);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion this method is the easiest because of it's ES6 syntax and the use of simple Array methods.

```js
let arr = (
    Array.from(
        {length: 4},
        (_, i) => 
            Array
                .from({length: i+1}, (_, j) => j)
                .join(' ')
    )
)

console.log(arr.join('\n'))
console.log(arr.reverse().join('\n'))
```

Here is the same thing, but with for loops:

```js
let arr = [];
for(const [lineI] of Array.from({length: 4}).entries()) {
    let l = [];
    for(const [numI] of Array.from({length: lineI+1}).entries()) {
        l.push(numI);
    }
    arr.push(l);
    console.log(l.join(' '));
}
console.log(arr.reverse().map(line => line.join(' ')).join('\n'))
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I am looking for. But, can we implement the for loop into the problem? How would you do it?

Answer (score 1):

This is a nice way to this:

```js
const list = [1, 2, 3, 4];

let i = 0 ;
while ( i < list.length ) {
  console.log( list.slice(0,++i).join(' ') );
}
while ( i >= 0 ) {
  console.log( list.slice(0,i--).join(' ') );
}
```